# List user of FTP in Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'd just would like to list all user (or all account name) on a ftp using Python.
I can connect to the ftp but not log in !

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("46.28.65.182")

ftp.connect()
```

This is the code.
So if you have a solution to do this you are welcome ! :)
I think that's easy but i'm a newbie ;)
Thanks all

Comment: What do you mean you cannot log in? Error? You didn't find the adequate function? Be specific. Show your code, errors, input, output, everything.

Comment: 'from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("46.28.65.182")
ftp.connect()'  This is the code ! I don't have the password and i **dont** want to hack it ! I juste want to see all user account on this ftp

Comment: Edit it into your question. Looks better and folks don't have to search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no FTP command to list all ftp user accounts on a system and it would also be considered a misfeature (security!) if such command would exist, and especially if it would be available for unauthorized users.

Since no such command exist ftplib can not offer such a command. You would need to have some other kind of (administrative) access to the machine and then look at the configuration of the FTP server to get these information.